# Why google plus need no activity registration in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm new on Android programming.

I think Google Plus uses Activity when signIn to Google Plus.
There is no Activity registration in AndroidManifest.xml of my project, but Google plus activity works fine.

Why Google Plus can use Acitivity with no registration? 
Is there anything I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

because it's a part of the google play services which if you  remember you will add as a **library**. also if you look further into the code that instantiates the service, you will see that google api client is invoked this way

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

which is nothing but a layer between your app and play services refer this link it's explained nicely here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#Starting